# Check if text within a list is withing a string

Tags: python

I would like to check against a list of words if they are within a string.

For Example:

```
listofwords = ['hi','bye','yes','no']

String = 'Hi how are you'
string2 = 'I have none of the words'
```

String 1 is true as it contains 'hi' and string2 is false as it does not.

I have tried the following code but it always returns false.

```
if any(ext in String for ext in listofwords):
   print(String)
```

I would also like to show what the matching word was to check this is correct.

Comment: do you want to print the entire string or only the matching words?

Comment: If your problem not solved please update the question.

Comment: @Poojan updated

Comment: Check updated answer. The key idea is to user `.lower` function on strings before making comparisons.  If you want to print words( here assuming words mean space seperated words) just iterate over and do matching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`hi` and `Hi` are different words. Use `.lower` before comparing.

```
if any(ext.lower() in String.lower() for ext in listofwords):
   print(String)
```

Update:

- to print matching word use for loop to iterate and print words that match.

Example:

```
listofwords = ['hi','bye','yes','no']

String = 'Hi how are you'
string2 = 'I have none of the words'

for word in listofwords:
    if word.lower() in map(str.lower,String.split()): # map both of the words to lowercase before matching
        print(word)


for word in listofwords:
    if word.lower() in map(str.lower,string2.split()): # map both of the words to lowercase before matching
        print(word)
```

PS: Not the optimized version. You can store `String.split` results in a list and then start iterating that will save time for larger strings. But purpose of the code is to demonstrate use of `lower` case.

Comment: @AndrejKesely OP stats his problem. Its returning `False` in every case given the code. I just gave suggestion on mistake. His code do not mention anything about `string2`

Comment: Would this also allow me to return the actual matched value in the string ->ext.lower()

Answer (score 2):

Python is case sensitive. Hence hi is not equal to Hi. This works:

```
listofwords = ['hi','bye','yes','no']

String = 'hi how are you'
string2 = 'I have none of the words'

if any(ext in String for ext in listofwords):
   print(String)
```

Comment: There is no need to change string manually. Instead use `lower` to do same. What will you do when string is very long or entered by user input.

Comment: Well, depends on your use case I would say

Answer (score 0):

The problem is both with case-sensitivity and with using `in` directly with a string.

If you want to make your search case-insensitive, consider converting both the `String` and the word to lower case, also, you should split the string after lower casing it, if you want to properly search for words:

```
if any(ext.lower() in String.lower().split() for ext in listofwords):
   print(String)
```

Splitting avoids returning `True` for strings like `no` in `none` and only works if `no` (or any other word) is present on its own. So now the above will work for both `String` (it will print it) and for `string2` (it will not print it).

Comment: Thanks for taking this 1 step further.

Would this also allow me to return the actual matched value in the string ->ext.lower()

Comment: @JarrattPerkins You can get the matched value, in fact there could be many values that exist in the list and in the string.